# Android Marshmallow usb problem moto g2

Tags: usb, 6.0-marshmallow, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging, motorola-moto-g2

My moto g2 is not being detected via USB when I connect it to my PC. It still charges however. Its not getting recognized since i have done marshmallow update. i have even enabled MTP in developer options. but still its not showing any notifications when connected. Please help me.

Comment: Does it show up in Device Manager (Windows) or in `lsusb` (Linux)?  (See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058134/is-there-an-equivalent-of-lsusb-for-os-x) for Mac.)

Answer (score 1):

My moto g3 had similar problem.  After connecting the USB cable the device would appear within windows explorer but no file structure would appear.  This is because the phone was in USB charge only mode.  I double tap the very top status bar and a USB notification appears as shown below.
[image: USB for file transfer]

After selecting the USB for file transfer notification the following display appears:
[image: USB for file transfer]

Select the MTP protocol (or PTP) and you should see the media of the phone appear in the explorer window.

Every time the phone is connected to USB it will default to charging mode.

I hope this was a useful tip!

Comment: This is a good tip, but the questioner said his phone doesn't show the notification when connected, so it's unlikely to be the issue here. I'm sure some other visitors will find it helpful, though. Welcome to our community!